# nextcloud in elementary file manager?

Tags: release-hera, pantheon-files

Folks; I'm using NextCloud client in elementary, all along with the NextCloud desktop sync app. I am *sure* I have seen a NextCloud icon in elementary file manager on the left side (just below Network) once or twice, but at the moment it's gone and I have no idea how to make it come back there... Any ideas?

Thanks,
Kristian

Comment: Files now has rudimentary cloud provider support for any client using the libcloudproviders DBus API. This includes NextCloud (maybe only NextCloud?). So, if a provider appears on this DBus then a corresponding entry should appear in the sidebar. I think the NextCloud client has to be running and connected for this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm ok. Thanks. It seems after re-installing the NextCloud client and linking it to my configuration again, now it's there in Files. Strange. But at least it's working. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Autostart Nextcloud desktop client in background

Should add `--background` switch to bin, example `/usr/bin/nextcloud --background`

Autostart folder location is `~/.config/autostart`